# Spresense-ArduinoでPublishしたメッセージをROSで確認する方法

Tags: spresense, arduino

Spresense-ArduinoのサンプルにあるGNSS情報受信するスケッチを編集し、受信したGNSS情報をカスタムメッセージとしてPublishし、別ノードでSubscribeしようとしています。

しかし、以下の通り実行するとエラーが出てしまいます。
これを解決する方法をご教授いただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

```
$ rosrun rosserial_arduino serial_node.py

[INFO] [1570687026.937388]: ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [1570687026.948129]: Connecting to /dev/ttyUSB0 at 115200 baud
[INFO] [1570687029.058494]: Requesting topics...
[ERROR] [1570687044.060114]: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
[INFO] [1570687044.061219]: Requesting topics...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ERROR] [1570687044.060114]: Unable to sync with device; possible link problem or link software version mismatch such as hydro rosserial_python with groovy Arduino
```

ボーレートを下げてみてはどうでしょうか？